# How to get cell's background color using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How do we get `background color` of a `XSSFCell`. I tried using `XSSFCellStyle` but no luck.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);

System.out.println(row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
```

Using these steps I am not able to get background color representation in `Short` type.

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: @AAA: Your code seems correct... what you are getting in this case... default it is showing 64 on my end...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh I am also getting 64 which is AUTOMATIC Color code it doesn't make any sense while your workbook is having some different color.

Comment: but try this 
`cell.getCellStyle().setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);`
   `System.out.println(cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());`

Will give you 51... means it's working and changing as per the color it gets.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh I tried this one also I am able to get other values other than 64 but if I set in Excel using any tool but not POI I am not able to fetch the background color. The excel files I am using are not made through POI but tool like Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this URL:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45492

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
            CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();          
            System.out.println("color = " + getColorPattern(cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor()));




private short[] getColorPattern(short colorIdx){        
    short[] triplet = null;
    HSSFColor color = palette.getColor(colorIdx);
    triplet = color.getTriplet();       
    System.out.println("color : " + triplet[0] +"," + triplet[1] + "," + triplet[2]);
    return triplet;
}
```

This returns the RGB codes but not exact ones. But its more or less the same color returned when compared with the actual color code in the XLS custom color picker.

Comment: What does palette refer to?

Comment: How would this work when cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor() or cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor() always return default values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
row.getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor().getARGBHex()
```

Notice that `Color` is used twice

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in scala but it's the same. Your code is right.

This is my, see if you can find differences:

```
val wb = new XSSFWorkbook(path)
for (id <- 0.until(sheetTot)) {
    val sh = wb.getSheetAt(id)    
    print(sh.rowIterator().next().cellIterator().next().getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor())
}
```

in my case the result is 64

Comment: If you will check every time and for different background  colors it will give you value 64 Which is `Automatic` color

Comment: Yes, 64 refers Automatic. But how do we get actual color?

Answer (score 0):

The following is in Scala but it does show exactly how to get the colour from the object model. I wanted to instantiate a java.awt.Color object from the actual rgb values (which is useful partly because my debugger displays for me the actual colour of the object when I stop at breakpoints, and partly because this is for export to systems that have nothing to do with Excel). I'm ignoring the colour's alpha value and my Scala may be a bit naive. I'd suggest that if this doesn't work for you, you should set a break-point and examine the result of closely related method calls such as getFillBackgroundColorColor()

```
val rgb: Array[Byte] = cell.getCellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor.getRgb
def toInt(b: Byte): Int = {
  if (b<0) 256+b else b
}
val rgbInts = rgb.map(toInt)
val color = new Color(rgbInts(0),rgbInts(1),rgbInts(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

All the time its giving me no 64 
this is my code

```
   for(Row r : my_sheet) {
        for (Cell c : r) {

            System.out.println(c.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor() );
            //if foreground filter color is not green then hide the record
            if ( c.getColumnIndex()==1  && c.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor() !=17){
                r1=(XSSFRow) c.getRow();
                if (r1.getRowNum()!=0) { /* Ignore top row */
                    /* Hide Row that does not meet Filter Criteria */
                    r1.getCTRow().setHidden(true); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The same happens for me.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several options of getting the background color. When the color of the cell is specified in the following way:

[image: Background color selection in excel]

The following returns the color code:

```
public static String getBackgroundColor(XSSFCell cell) {
  byte[] rgbWithTint = cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor().getRGBWithTint();
  if (rgbWithTint == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return Hex.encodeHexString(rgbWithTint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem to only get the color index **64** every time I tried to read a color from a cell.

After a lot of try-and-error I found out, that the worksheet had *conditionally coloring* activated. It seems that you can not read the background color by `cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor()` if that is the case.

After this realization, in my use case, I simply looked at the conditions the color is based on and extracted the information I needed. So I had no need to read the actual color I only needed to distinguish between states.

Anyway I am sure that there is a possibility to read such a conditionally filled color with Apache POI. A good starting point might be the  [Quick-Guide to conditionally coloring](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting).