# Get Cell color in excel with poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I read all questions on so but no answer was working. If i change the cell color in excel i still get 0 and 64. I am using excel 2007 and poi 3.11. Thanks for help.

```
try{ File file = new File("C:\\Test\\poi.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Tabelle1");
    XSSFCellStyle cs = sh.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle();   
    System.out.println("Color: "+cs.getFillForegroundColor()); // 0
    System.out.println("Color: "+cs.getFillBackgroundColor()); // 64
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499739/how-do-i-get-the-java-apache-poi-hssf-background-color-for-a-given-cell

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491231/how-to-get-cells-background-color-using-apache-poi

Comment: The Problem is if i change the color in my cell i still get the same vaules 0 and 64 so the other posts dont answer my question

Comment: Details like that help in the post haha. Please add that as your code doesn't suggest that either. But from the comments on the other links I posted, apparently 64 is the `Automatic` color

Comment: Have you tried: `cs.getFillBackgroundColorColor().getRgb()` ? Notice the word `Color` is used twice

Comment: I tried    `cs.getFillBackgroundColorColor().getRgb()` returns null

Comment: try it with `getFillForegroundColorColor()` as well? With POI, you need to set use `setForegroundColor` to set the background color haha. That's what I meant to type before.

Comment: I have an excel file created witch Microsoft ecxel 2007 i want to get the color of cell why should i call `setForegroundColor()` ?

Comment: just try: `cs.getFillForegroundColorColor().getRgb()`

Comment: I tried it returns a byte array with [-1,-1,-1]

Comment: That's a byte[] for RGB. You can try: `getARGBHex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cs.getFillForegroundColorColor().getARGBHex()
```

This will return the ARGB in hex

**UPDATE**

To check the color, you can do:

```
Color color = cs.getFillForegroundColorColor();

if (color.GREY_25_PERCENT || color.GREY_40_PERCENT || color.GREY_50_PERCENT || color.GREY_80_PERCENT)
    // is grey
}
```

OR if it's only 2 colors used:

```
Color color = cs.getFillForegroundColorColor();

if (color.WHITE) {
  // is white
}else {
  // is grey
}
```

Comment: Not a problem! Glad we could figure it out :-)

Comment: it worked when i used yellow as a color but when the color is grey it returns FFFFFFFF  and when the color is white it also returns FFFFFFFF so how do i know if the color is grey or white?

Comment: Are you allowing for any color for the background or only a set of colors?

Comment: The color is either white or grey and i want to find the grey cells

Comment: I added another way to check in the answer. If you can give me the RGB values in the byte[] from before, I think I know a way to give you a way to get the exact value.

Comment: Which byte[] do you mean?

Comment: `getRgb()` method call you did first

Comment: Ok i call `cs.getFillForegroundColorColor().getRgb()` returns [-1,-1,-1]